# How to check that the Enter key was pressed in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the program written below, if I hit enter, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Claude/Desktop/practice.py", line 11, in <module>
    guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''*
```

I could not find an answer while searching ways to to detect if the "Enter" key was pressed. Could someone help?

```
from random import randint

# Generates a number from 1 through 10 inclusive
random_number = randint(1, 10)

guesses_left = 6

while (guesses_left > 0):

        guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
        if (guess == random_number):
            print ("You win!")
            ans = input("Do you want to play again?:")
        if (ans == 'y' or ans == 'Y'):
            guesses_left = 5
            guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
        else:
            break
    #elif (guess == ""):
    #   print ("Please enter a number between 1 and 10")
    elif(guess != random_number):        
        guesses_left -= 1
else:
    print ("You lose!")
```

Comment: It might be operating system specific.

Answer (score 3):

When you just press enter when in an `input` prompt, then you essentially entered an empty string. So you would be trying to convert an empty string to a number here which doesn’t work. Instead, you should just look at the string first and see if it’s empty in which case the user just pressed enter, otherwise try to convert it:

```
guess = input("Your guess: ")
if not guess:
    print("You didn't enter anything. So let's abort.")
    break

try:
    # try converting it to a number
    guess = int(guess)
except ValueError:
    # ValueError is raised when that didn't work
    print("That wasn't a number!")
else:
    # otherwise we now have a number which we can use
    if guess == random_number:
        print('You win')

    # …
```

Answer (score 0):

its because of `Your guess` !

The [int(x)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function Convert a number or string x to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments are given. If x is a number, it can be a plain integer, a long integer, or a floating point number. If x is floating point, the conversion truncates towards zero. If the argument is outside the integer range, the function returns a long object instead.
If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string or Unicode object representing an integer literal in radix base. !

if you have python 2.x you can use [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) function for general input from users.,

Comment: OP is using Python 3, so there is no `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by getting "Enter" code by using ord().
print(ord(key.char))
13
if ord(key.char) == 13:
print("Enter Pressed")
else:
print("Any other key Pressed")