# Detect enter key pressed python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, keyboard

is there a way to detect if ENTER is pressed with python? I was able to detect letters with win32api using `win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(ord('H'))` , but couldn't do the same with enter. I need to run the code on windows.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701407/how-to-check-that-the-enter-key-was-pressed-in-python

Comment: @tlfong01 the only thing relating that question to this question is the title.

Comment: `win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(13)`?

Comment: @Axa319, Ah so there is a condition, of using win32Api.

Comment: Console application? GUI application? Something else? Please show a [mcve]. Also do take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyboard lib.

pip3 install keyboard

```
import keyboard

if keyboard.read_key() == "enter":
    ...
```

https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard

Comment: Thank you for your answer, using virtal-key code was also a possible solution